# Can we handle HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException using Exception class

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to implement exception handling in spring boot application. Here I am handling all exception using `Exception.class`. I have one Quation can this method handle `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException`?  If yes then when I am trying to access wrong method from postman I am not getting any response (default as well as my response).

Using following method I am able to handle `NullPointerException`, `DataRetrievalFailureException` etc. but not able to handle `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException`

**RestExceptionHandler**

```
import com.spacestudy.model.ExceptionMessage;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {


    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ExceptionMessage> handleAllExceptionMethod(Exception ex,WebRequest requset,HttpServletResponse res) {


        ExceptionMessage exceptionMessageObj = new ExceptionMessage();

        exceptionMessageObj.setStatus(res.getStatus());
        exceptionMessageObj.setError(ex.getLocalizedMessage());     
        exceptionMessageObj.setException(ex.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        exceptionMessageObj.setPath(((ServletWebRequest) requset).getRequest().getServletPath());  

        return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionMessage>(exceptionMessageObj, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

from https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.html you can see that `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` has `java.lang.Exception` as a parent, thus your exception handler will handle it as well. 
Btw, you can easily test that manually by sending POST request on URL which supports only GET requests

Comment: when I am trying to access any wrong method I am not getting any response. other exception are handling

Answer (score 0):

The `@ExceptionHandler` seeks for the specific exception first (ex. `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException`) and if the controller for it is not found, the handler for the generic exception is used `Exception.class`.

To answer your question: **YES**, your controller should be capable to catch `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` exception as well.

Take a look on the Spring docs of [`@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html). On of the points in the beginning say:

> An exception argument: declared as a general Exception or as a more specific exception.

Comment: but when I am accessing get request as post from postman I am not getting any response

Comment: Hm, it should work... Try to annotate the `handleAllExceptionsMetho` with `@ResponseBody` annotation.

Comment: I tried with this `@ResponseBody`. not getting any response

Answer (score 0):

You can override handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported method from ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.
Lool at this article (5th item): https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api

For example

```
    @Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported(final HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex,
                                                                     final HttpHeaders headers,
                                                                     final HttpStatus status,
                                                                     final WebRequest request) {

    
    return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
}
```